# NRPE commands doesn't work when called from remote management host

Tags: linux, permissions, nagios, nrpe

First of all: I know there were already questions about this issue, but even using their answers I still cannot figure out why my command is not working.
What I want to do is call a script on remote host using NRPE. However, this what the script is going to do may be only executed by specific user (let's call him `userA`).

- Now, my NRPE command looks like:

  `command[debug_now]=/usr/local/bin/debug_now`
- My sudoers have entry
  `nagios ALL=(tomcat)     NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/debug_now` as I noticed user calling the scripts from nrpe.cfg is called `nagios`.
- Script `/usr/local/bin/debug_now` looks like:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  whoami
  echo "Debug..."
  sudo -u tomcat whoami
  echo "Debug finished"
  ```

Script above has same permissions as other scripts can be executed by user `nagios`. What's more, when it is executed locally it pretty prints:

```
nagios
Debug... 
tomcat
Debug finished
```

and it's generally working as intended. However, when it's called from management host, it prints only

```
nagios
Debug...
Debug finished
```

This is caused probably by `NRPE: Cannot read output`, which appears every time I try to `sudo` anything from management host. I already tried adding to sudoers entry `Defaults !requiretty` with no success. I use Debian 6.0.7. What can I do to make my script work, when called from management host?

**EDIT.**
First of all, directory `/etc/sudoers.d/` contains only file README.
`userA` real name should be `tomcat`
Let's take a look at `visudo` output then:

```
 Defaults        env_reset
 Defaults !requiretty
 root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
 nagios ALL=(tomcat)     NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/whoami

 %www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - www
 %tomcat ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - tomcat
 %tomcat ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/tomcat stop
 %tomcat ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/tomcat start
 %tomcat ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/tomcat restart
```

Please note I tried even `nagios ALL=(tomcat)     NOPASSWD: ALL` and `nagios ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD: ALL`. I also removed few user entries like `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`.

NRPE

```
 $ tail -n 1 /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
 command[debug_now]=/usr/local/bin/debug_now
```

```
 $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/debug_now
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 573 Dec  2 09:06 /usr/local/bin/debug_now
 $ ls -lh /usr/local | grep bin
 drwxrwsr-x  2 root      staff 4.0K Dec  2 09:12 bin
 $ ls -lh /usr | grep local
 drwxrwsr-x  14 root staff 4.0K Oct 22  2010 local
```

From another host

```
$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <ip address> -c debug_now
nagios
Debug...
Debug finished
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh God, I feel so ashamed right now.
Everything is fine. You need to **RESTART** `nagios-nrpe-server` after changing `sudoers`, reload is not enough. Reload is fine if you only change `nrpe.cfg` or other config file.

@MadHatter, @Keith - thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `sudoers` entry specifies privileges to run `/usr/local/bin/debug_now`, but your script says `sudo -u userA whoami`.  This will not work; whatever command you want to run with `sudo` privileges, that is what must appear in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I tried adding entry `nagios ALL=(userA)     NOPASSWD: ALL` in my sudoers. Script works if it's called locally (just like before), but still is not working when called from management host.

Comment: @spoko: when you say "*works if it's called locally*", what do you mean?  Do you mean if it's invoked from the local shell, or if it's called locally **via NRPE**?

Comment: I used local shell to call the script as nagios: `sudo -u nagios /usr/local/bin/debug_now`.

Comment: Might this be a more general NRPE problem?  Have you any other commands running *correctly* from this server via NRPE?

Comment: Yes, I do have a whole bunch of other commands. They all work fine, no matter if they are called from management host via NRPE or invoked in local shell. None of them uses `sudo` though.

Comment: What does NRPE log (in syslog) when this happens?

Comment: My feeling is we **really** need to see your `sudoers` file.  Could you edit the whole thing into your question?  Also the output of `ls -al /usr/local/bin/debug_now`?

Comment: @MadHatter I edited it and put `sudo visudo` output there.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your problem on a Debian Squeeze (6.0.10) box, but I had no trouble. If you set things up exactly like this (**with the correct sudo setup**, as MadHatter points out), including permissions and modes being correct, it will behave as you expect.

```
# ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/nagios-test 
-r--r----- 1 root root 44 Dec  1 11:36 /etc/sudoers.d/nagios-test
# cat /etc/sudoers.d/nagios-test 
nagios ALL=(keith)  NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/whoami

# tail -n 1 /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
command[debug]=/usr/local/bin/debug
# ls -l /usr/local/bin/debug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 75 Dec  1 11:37 /usr/local/bin/debug

# cat /usr/local/bin/debug
#!/bin/sh
whoami
echo "Debug..."
sudo -u keith whoami
echo "Debug finished"
```

From another host:

```
$ ./check_nrpe -H squeeze -c debug
nagios
Debug...
keith
Debug finished
```

Comment: +1 from me; that's heroic!

Comment: Mostly because I couldn't think of anything that would cause the stated problem, so was starting to question my own sanity. Wanted to double-check that we were providing correct information.

Comment: @Keith if only I could +1 your answer, I would. Thanks for your effort, that's truely heroic and therefore I feel doomed, as this doesn't work. I edited my question, added few more things MadHatter asked.